# Software or Hardware?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, ssd, raid

Hi guys i have a Server 2008 R2 thats a supermicro Duel Xeon 1366 box 12gb DDR3, that i use for file storage and WDS and little Vmware Workstation 12 stuff.. The issue am having

its loaded with 2 kingston v300 SSDs as boot drives in Raid 0 from an intel controller with just the OS installed..

6 Drives for storage all SATA 2 mainly seagate pipeline HD2 500GB...

basicly i removed a dying drive that showed bad sectors and give off bad SMART data, i wanted to replace the drive with 1 TB Seagate Baracada brand new..

When i installed, the drive and tried to copy files to it from a known good drive, it locks up and windows locks up with it as well, the explorer will stop responding too and will take about 5 mins to come back to life.

Copying to and from the other drives works flawless.

I have checked the new drive is fine by checking SMART data in another pc and writing data till the drive is full and replaced the raid controller in the server to rule that out.

any Ideas? This pecking my head!

PS, Also reinstalled windows server to make sure...